# Join two string properties (firstName + lastName) of usercontrol and assign it to label

Tags: c#, winforms

I made a custom usercontrol which contains a label.
I have 3 string properties : firstName, lastName, fullName.

How can I set the label's text = FullName ?

```
    public string firstName
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public string lastName
    {
        get; set;
    }

     public string fullName //this fails
    {

        get { return string.Format("{0} {1}", firstName, lastName); }
        set { labelFullName.Text = value; }
    }
```

Comment: WPF or WinForms? What label? I see some code, but you don't say what class it's in. What class is it in? What are you trying to accomplish in the setter on `fullName`?

Comment: Seems like you'd want `fullName` to be read only and then update `labelFullName` on changes to `firstName` and `lastName`.

Comment: "this fails": What does that mean? Is it the setter that "fails" or the getter? Does it crash? What is the expected behavior? What is the observed behavior?

Comment: Hey, it's a Winform, this part of code is in my UserControl class

Comment: Well it doesn't set the FullName to the label..

Comment: @Niiw Thanks. Please answer the other questions as well.

Comment: WHAT doesn't set the FullName to the label (or the label's text to the FullName, more likely)? Are you saying you never call any of this code?

Comment: Is this code in the Subclassed Label's class?

Comment: The UserControl has a Label, normally what is expect is when I declare my usercontrol and assign for example myUserctrl.firstName = "Bob"; & myUserctrl.lastName = "John"; The label of this usercontrol shoud be "Bob John";

Comment: I understood what you wanted to do. Check my answer, this is how I would do it. You might need to tweak a little

Comment: @t.m. This is what it looks like http://imgur.com/a/XAKma

Comment: When you assign names the UI won't know that something changed and UI needs to be updated. You should probably implement some notifier for that  see INotifyPropertyChanged.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like Windows Form to me. In WPF you would be using labelFullName.Content property. Assuming you want to set the label as the fullname each time first name or last name changes, then one option would be to do this within your UserControl class:

```
private String _sFirstName = "";
private String _sLastName = "";

public String FirstName { 
  get { return _sFirstName; }
  set { _sFirstName = value; UpdateLabel(); }
}
public String LastName { 
  get { return _sLastName; }
  set { _sLastName = value; UpdateLabel(); }
}
public String FullName {
  get { return _sFirstName + " " + _sLastName; }
}
private void UpdateLabel() {
  // do within a UI thread to prevent threading issues
  this.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => {
    labelFullName.Text = this.FullName.Trim();
  }));
}
```

Comment: Just to add to @John's answer, the reason your original code is not working is that you are updating the value of the label only when the setter of the FullName property is called and I am guessing that is never the case. If you want to update the label, it must happen when either property is modified, as John has demonstrated in his answer.

Comment: @John I tried this code, it gives me an exception saying "Cannot use BeginInvoke while the handle of the windows hasn't been created.."

Comment: Okay got It working, I set UpdateLabel() to public & used the method AFTER adding the usercontrol to the form, thanks :) e.g :
this.Controls.Add(myUserControl);
myUserControl.UpdateLabel();

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Regarding BeginInvoke() - the control must be added to the form before you can use that. I omitted that from the code because it wasn't in context. Glad you got it working.